# Compare values and combine

Tags: php, arrays, combiners

How can I combine the text values of the same pr value?

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [ID] => 1 [text] => text1 [pr] => project1) 
[1] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [text] => text2 [pr] => project1)
[2] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [text] => text3 [pr] => project2)
[3] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [text] => text4 [pr] => project2)
[4] => Array ( [ID] => 2 [text] => text5 [pr] => project1)
)
```

Output:

```
$newarray = array(
        "project1" => "text1 | text2 | text5",
        "project2" => "text3 | text4",
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
<?php

$array = Array(
    0 => Array('ID' => 1, 'text' => 'text1', 'pr' => 'project1'),
    1 => Array('ID' => 2, 'text' => 'text2', 'pr' => 'project1'),
    2 => Array('ID' => 2, 'text' => 'text3', 'pr' => 'project2'),
    3 => Array('ID' => 2, 'text' => 'text4', 'pr' => 'project2'),
    4 => Array('ID' => 2, 'text' => 'text5', 'pr' => 'project1'),
);


$newArray = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $newArray[$item['pr']][] = $item['text'];
}

foreach ($newArray as $k => $v) {
    $newArray[$k] = implode(' | ', $v);
}


var_dump($newArray);
```

Output:

> array(2) { ["project1"]=> string(21) "text1 | text2 | text5"
>   ["project2"]=> string(13) "text3 | text4" }

Answer (score 2):

Just loop your array and create new array.

```
$newArray = [];

foreach ($myArray as $elements) {
    if (isset($newArray[$elements['pr']])) {
        $newArray[$elements['pr']] .= " | {$elements['text']}";
    } else {
        $newArray[$elements['pr']] = $elements['text'];
    }

}
```

Comment: Throws an error (don't get it %)P http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57920134e116c3fb40a2ca562e624f34a8d39a85.

Comment: @DOCASAREL Just few typos. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1de62d53757bf5a726bf868d29f95744b26cb205

Answer (score 1):

This also makes sure that a certain text is added only once per project.

```
$newarray = array();

// Loop through the old array, set the current row to the $row variable
foreach($oldarray as $row)
{
  // If the project doesn't yet exist in the new array, we create an empty array for it
  if(!array_key_exists($row["pr"], $newarray))
  {
    $newarray[$row["pr"]] = array();
  }

  // We add the current text to the array of the project, but only if it is not already there
  if(!in_array($row["text"], $newarray[$row["pr"]]))
  {
    $newarray[$row["pr"]][] = $row["text"];
  }
}

// Loop through the new array, and stich the texts within the project-array together with the separator `|`
foreach($newarray as $k => $v)
{
  $newarray[$k] = implode(" | ", $v);
}
```

There are of course shorter solutions that use more advanced array functions, but this one is easier to understand. Note: the code is untested.

Comment: Throws a lot of errors: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59a23f217338d36309b3109ffec141bbc61070c1.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to close a parenthesis. Fixed.

Comment: Cool. Works. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d642909076abbd6b69a1fdc338a7bfd6067b1002. "Code tested!" %)P